# Why are the coefficients of the reciprocal of this characteristic polynomial positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, tensor-products

Let $V$ be some real vector space and $V_{\mathbb{C}}=V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ be the base change to the complex numbers (therefore it has a conjugation action on it naturally). Let $F$ be an endomorphism of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ (self map of complex vector spaces. Consider the map $F \otimes \overline{F}$ defined by setting $\overline{F}$ to be the endomorphism of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ defined by $\overline{F}(x)=\overline{F(\overline{x})}$ (basically conjugate apply $F$ then conjugate again). The question is why does the reciprocal characterisic polynomial of $F \otimes \overline{F}$ as an endomorphism of $V_{\mathbb{C}} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_{\mathbb{C}}$ have positive real coefficients. (I can show it's real). By reciprocal I mean take $det(1-t(F \otimes \overline{F}))^{-1}$ in the power series ring $\mathbb{C} [[t]] $.

Motivation: It's used in the book by Kiehl-Weissaur on proof of Weil conjectures (but I think it's just linear algebra)

Partial work: I can reduce to the case $F$ is diagonal and it becomes some inequality on the eigenvalues which I don't think is trivial (I could be wrong). Anyhow showing it's real is not hard.

Comment: It might help to write the coefficients of $T = F \otimes \bar F$ as $(-1)^k\operatorname{Tr}(\wedge^k T)$

Comment: There is something strange going on here. From considering the diagonal case, it looks to me as though $F \otimes \bar F$ will necessarily have positive roots corresponding to $|\lambda|^2$ for eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $F$. However, if the characteristic polynomial  has positive roots, it can't also have positive coefficients.

Comment: Ah shoot! You're right, sorry sorry I'll fix the question I misread (but still I don't know how to do this)

Comment: Does this not reduce to the diagonal case by continuity?

Comment: that may be true but the diagonal case isn't trivial i think

Comment: Can you show what you have in the diagonal case?

Comment: I got something very complicated